# Hide div gradually on scrolldown using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, hide

I want to hide a div gradually when scrolling down  beginning with the bottom until  reach the top .

Comment: Haven't you tried anything by yourself?

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is not a question. See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

you can use $anchorScroll
https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview
have a look at this.it is there in angular doc.https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll.
you can see documentation here.

```
<body ng-app="anchorScrollExample">
  <div id="scrollArea" ng-controller="ScrollController">
  <a ng-click="gotoBottom()">Go to bottom</a>
  <a id="bottom"></a> You're at the bottom!
</div>
</body>


angular.module('anchorScrollExample', [])
  .controller('ScrollController', ['$scope', '$location', '$anchorScroll',
    function ($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
      $scope.gotoBottom = function() {
        // set the location.hash to the id of
        // the element you wish to scroll to.
        $location.hash('bottom');

        // call $anchorScroll()
        $anchorScroll();
      };
    }]);
})(window.angular);
```